# Sitecore Forms Save submit action null FormDataModel

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am trying to create a form with Sitecore Forms on 9.3. No matter what I do with the save action I get the following error:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.BaseFormBuilderController.ProcessFormData(FormDataModel data) +66
Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController.Index(FormDataModel data) +54
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +138
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +34
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__0() +79
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +466
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +466
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +524
```

Comment: can you add your custom save action ?

Comment: This is a bad request. It turns out, the problem was that I minified the forms js files, and that breaks the form. This is extremely frustrating. I cant minify the js?craziness.

Answer (score 3):

The error you see is happening because the `NavigationDataModelBinder` which runs before it gets to `BaseFormBuilderController.ProcessFormData` has not been able to set the `NavigationData` due to these checks:

```
  string[] buttonValues = this.GetButtonValues(buttonId, bindingContext);
  if (buttonValues != null && buttonValues.Length <= 1)
    return (NavigationData) null;
  int result1;
  if (!int.TryParse(buttonValues?[1], out result1))
    return (NavigationData) null;
```

This happens when for some reason the Submit button on the form does not send at least 2 values where the 2nd value is an `int`.

From the couple of times I've seen this it is because of some javascript that is catching the submit click event and doing `event.preventDefault();` or `event.stopPropagation();` which prevents the jquery unobstrusive ajax handler from getting the value when serializing it.

So look for things like a `document.click()` handler that could be interrupting this.

When you say that un-minifying the javascript has helped, then it could be a race condition somewhere. Also check that the form isn't being submitted twice somehow via double event handler registration.